# How can I limit pppd record file size?

Tags: linux, pppd

My mother tongue is not English, sorry for my English.

I use pppd with a GPRS module.

I use like `pppd record record.pcap call tdscdma` command to access Internet.And `pppdump record.pcap` or `wireshark` to show the `record.pcap`.

when `pppd` run ,the `record.pcap` will save all data and the file size getting bigger and bigger.

Now I am just want save last(Newest) 1Mb(for example,or quantity) message.And how can I limit the file size.

I am more concerned about the recent network conditions. FIFO is not necessary.if the file bigger than 1Mb, truncate it to zero is OK too.

`[root@AT91SAM9-RT9x5 logs]# pppd -v
pppd: unrecognized option '-v'
pppd version 2.4.5`

`[root@AT91SAM9-RT9x5 logs]# uname -a
Linux AT91SAM9-RT9x5 2.6.39 #34 Wed Jun 4 16:12:41 CST 2014 armv5tejl GNU/Linux`

Use wireshark looks like this:
[image: with-wireshark]

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `tcpdump` program for capturing traffic of `ppp0` interface?

There are -C  and -W options for limiting size of output files.

Example:

```
tcpdump -i ppp0 -C 1 -W 2 -w file.pcap
```

See more from man page: tcpdump(8).

Comment: I can use tcpdump.But it seem to be not able to dump the ppp's `AT command` like `send (AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"cmnet\"^M)` , `expect (OK)` .Or maybe when ppp0 interface up,and tcpdump not run immediately.

Comment: Yep, tcpdump only captures IP traffic of ppp.